# OrientDB bean unique field

Tags: java, javabeans, orientdb

I am trying to make unique bean field for OrientDB but can't find how found only @Id @Version annotations.
I work as object database.

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a UNIQUE index against the field you want to be unique.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX User.id UNIQUE
```

Look at: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Indexes#Create_an_index